# How to Change Screen Resolution programmatically in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to Change Screen resolution when my application launches .My form size is bigger than my Screen resolution so when i modify by resolution to an bigger through regedit .It can be seen properly
 So i want a code which itself do changing of screen resolution

Comment: What happens if my screen doesn't support that resolution? You shouldn't force the user to have *his* resolution fit *your* application; but the other way around - you need to make ***your application*** adapt to the current resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some documentation on MSDN about that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

On that page scroll to "Task 2: Changing the Display Resolution".