# How to change the resolution of my application

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a C# WinForms Aplication and the actual form has the size of 1920x1080, and I have around 10-15 picture boxes + 20-25 buttons etc. All of them are sized to look nice in the form. However, some of my friends don't have 1920x1080 resolution on their PC so how can I change the resolution ( I know, I said "resolution" like 100 times) of my aplication so they can use it too? I want to make it 1280x800.

Someone asked a similar question, and someone else said: use form.MaximumSize = new size. However if I do this my aplication crashes. So what can I do?

Thanks alot to everyone !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673046/how-to-change-screen-resolution-programmatically-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks CodingGorilla!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131779/resize-controls-with-form-resize

Comment: Marc I don't need that, I want to change the resolution not resize the controls whenever I maximize the aplication.

Comment: @AlexKayz You don't need to change resolution. The resolution is not related to your application, it is a system setting. You should create your application in a way which can work with any resolution. For example you can use `Dock` and `Anchor` properties. Also you can use `AutoScroll` property of containers.

Comment: @AlexKayz your application doesn't know what a 'resolution' is. It has objects that are given a certain size (Width and Height), and it renders them appropriately. By using properties like Anchor and Dock, and tools like FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel, you can create an application which can allow items to change size based on the resolution they're being displayed at. If you want to make your application 1280x800, set your main form to that size (set the Width and Height of your form), and then design appropriately.

Comment: Alright thanks to everyone and sorry for these questions, I am still new to C#.